# Как называется явление, когда два глагола стоят рядом в одной форме

Tags: глаголы

> Пойди принеси воды, зайди купи хлеба, сядь посиди, приди взгляни, попробуй разберись. Или
>    Пойти разобраться, зайти купить, попробовать найти.

Надо ли их разделять запятой? Думаю, что не надо. Но хотелось бы правила из достоверного источника. И как это явление называется? Явно не однородные члены предложения. С инфинитивом, наверное, второй, как дополнение.

The same in English or related https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113680/imperative-with-go-go-do-something

Comment: Во всех этих парах глаголов можно между ними вставить союз «и» без особой потери общего смысла, поэтому такие пары больше похожи на однородные члены предложения, чем на конструкцию глагол – дополнение, тем более, что глагол в личной форме дополнением никак не может быть.  Сериальность, как подтверждает @Alex_ander, это первое, что приходит в голову для определения такого явления.

Comment: @YellowSky, опубликуйте, пожалуйста, ваш комментарий как ответ.

Comment: In English it's a quazi-serial verb construction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В случае, когда два глагола стоят в **одинаковой форме**, причем одно указывает способ, а второе цель действия, имеет место **осложненное глагольное сказуемое**.

Запятые в этом случае не ставятся.

[dic.academic.ru](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/996/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5)

Answer (score 5):

Конструкции с такими двойными глаголами иногда относят к *сериальным конструкциям* (соотв., **явление сериализации**).

[*Рассказы о сновидениях: Корпусное исследование устного русского дискурса, под ред. Кибрика и Подлесской, "Языки славянских культур", Москва 2009*](https://books.google.ru/books?id=WavJAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2&source=bl&ots=LHURxDKYJZ&sig=vMst6aun2baYKRsJNNFCkpkC-00&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR3-6P1vvTAhUGjiwKHSiPDq4Q6AEIQzAG)

Comment: Отличная книга, спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

В дополнение к предыдущим ответам - в большинстве случаев я бы не стал писать запятую, даже если бы мне предъявили самые, самые авторитетные источники, солидные и в кожаных переплётах. Кроме правил есть ещё и здравый смысл. Стоит отметить, тем не менее, что в ряде случаев запятая грамматически уместна, но меняет смысл.

Сравните:

> Надо пойти купить хлеба.

и

> Мне нужен переходник, но так лень его доставать. Ведь это же надо куда-то пойти, купить.

@YellowSky прав, когда говорит, что между двумя глаголами можно поставить союз "и" - в обоих случаях можно заменить на "пойти и купить". Но по смыслу в первом случае это не перечисление, не последовательная цепочка действий (как во втором случае), а как бы цельное действие, пусть даже и выполненное в несколько приёмов.

Ещё примеры:

> Приди взгляни на него! Смотри он что учудил опять.

и

> А ты туда приди, взгляни на него молча, и пусть ему станет стыдно.

Так что я предложил бы такое эмпирическое правило:
Если по смыслу между глаголами уместно вставить "а потом" - ставьте запятую. Если нет - не ставьте.

Comment: Отличное эмпирическое правило, и вот подтверждающий пример: "Снимаю, порчу" ))